# Internet Explorer Element ID bug with, at least, SELECT tag; doesn't need document.getElementById to recognize it

Tags: internet-explorer, select, getelementbyid

I'm refactoring some(body else's) code and, I've seen this before some time ago, and I don't remember the reason why it's happening.  There's a SELECT tag in HTML that looks like this:

```
<SELECT id="model"></SELECT>
```

In JavaScript, there is a statement which adds an option to the SELECT tag:

```
model.options[i]=option;
```

This works fine in Internet Explorer (tested in IE 7 and 8) for some reason.  It should fire an error but it does not.  However, in a browser like FireFox, this raises an error, as it should, for the code should be:

```
document.getElementById("model").options[i]=option;
```

What is the reason behind this, besides the fact that Internet Explorer prefers not to conform to W3C standards?  Is this just an issue with SELECT or any number of tags?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, Internet Explorer creates global variables corresponding to the `id` attributes of elements.

So when you create an element...

```
<select id="wtv"></select>
```

... under the hood IE initializes a global variable `wtv` to be a DOM object for that element. But the other browsers don't do this, so `wtv` is undefined.

Some citations:

- [MSDN Blogs - Internet Explorer creates global variables for each object in the DOM](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alvar/archive/2009/10/22/internet-explorer-creates-global-variables-for-each-object-in-the-dom.aspx)
- [Internet Explorer – Elements with an ID get a matching global variable in JS.](http://www.mehigh.biz/js/internet-explorer-elements-with-an-id-get-a-matching-global-variable-in-js.html)
- [Internet Explorer Global Variable Blow ups](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Mar/22/Internet-Explorer-Global-Variable-Blow-ups)

Comment: +1. yep, this is a legacy IE-specific 'feature', dating from the days of IE4. No other browser supports it, nor will they ever support it. IE continues to support it for backward compatibility reasons, but don't rely on that continuing indefinitely either.

Comment: @user717236 - If this answer helped, don't forget to [accept it using the green tick](http://www.mitalia.net/images/so/accepted_tick.png). [You can read more about accepting answers on meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)